# Exception when deploying a HttpCalloutMock

Tags: nullpointerexception, salesforce, httprequest, apex-code

I developed a functionality that makes use of `HttpRequest` class. In order to test it I used `HttpCalloutMock`. This functionality is within a `@future (callout=true)` method. I developed the test classes following the documentation for `HttpCalloutMock`. The tests (2) pass in sandbox, but when deploying to production they both give error `System.NullPointerException` (apparently the `HttpResponse` is null) in the assertion line. Here is the code for the tests and the implementations for `HttpCalloutMock` within the same Test class:

```
@isTest
global class TrustCalloutTest {

    global class TrustCalloutMockBasicCallout implements HttpCalloutMock {

        global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setBody('TEST');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }

    global class TrustCalloutMockRequestKey implements HttpCalloutMock {

        global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setBody('RECEIVED');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }

    static testmethod void testCalloutRequireKey() {

        HttpResponse res; 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TrustCalloutMockRequestKey());
        res = TrustCallout.requestTransferKey('BLAH','https://beta2.trustpoint.fi/API/requirekey.php');
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
    static testmethod void testCalloutBasicCallout(){

        HttpResponse res;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TrustCalloutMockBasicCallout()); 
        res = TrustCallout.basicCallout('BLAH','https://beta2.trustpoint.fi/API/committransfer.php');
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());    
    }
}
```

The actual callout works normally, and it also follows the documentation. Can you spot something wrong?

Thanks.

MGA.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very strange, and would point to something that's different between your sandbox and production environment.

Is it possible that your `TrustCallout.requestTransferKey()` method isn't actually calling `Http.send()` for some reason, and returning `Null`?

Have you looked at a debug log from the test run to follow the execution path?  Can you add `System.debug()` calls to `requestTransferKey()` and confirm that it's still calling `Http.send()`?  And that your code in `TrustCalloutMockRequestKey.respond()` is actually running?